# Barra de progresso de video não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, html

Eu preciso mostra um vídeo na view usando c#. O vídeo até roda, mas a barra de progresso não funciona corretamente.
Atualmente se eu mexo e adianto o vídeo ou atraso o vídeo pela barra de progresso; não acontece nada.

Assim está minha view   `<video id="video" width="100%"  preload="none" type="video/mp4" controls></video>`
e assim está o javascript  `video.src = "@Url.Content("~/")Noticia/VisualizarVideo?id=@ViewBag.ID";`

Assim está meu controller

````
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult VisualizarVideo(int id)
        {
            byte[] fileData = new byte[0];
           
               var noticia = db.NOTICIAS.Where(e => e.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
         
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(noticia.VIDEO == null ? fileData : noticia.VIDEO);
           return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue(noticia.VIDEO_CONTENT_TYPE).MediaType);
            
        }```
````

Comment: Cara a sua pergunta não tem nada a ver com asp, mvc ou c#... é puramente html e javascript, apresente um [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todos!
Mas a resposta é que o no servidor estava faltando aceitar  HTTP range requests. Então ficou assim meu controller:

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593310/streaming-videos-with-asp-net-core-3

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult VisualizarVideo(int id)
        {
            byte[] fileData = new byte[0];
           
               var noticia = db.NOTICIAS.Where(e => e.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
         
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(noticia.VIDEO == null ? fileData : noticia.VIDEO);

            Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");


            return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue(noticia.VIDEO_CONTENT_TYPE).MediaType);
            
        }
```